# Sizset sizcache on internet explorer bug

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

if you look at it on mozilla or chrome, the wrapper centers well on the screen and dont have the "sizset and sizcache" attributes that ie9- ie8- ie7 puts to it, also it doesn´t center on IE I think because of that bug, anybody know what´s the problem with that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You didn't specified any Doctype, then your page is in Quirks mode on IE.</strike>

Add this line on the very first line of your file :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

**EDIT :**

Well, I just seen you've got an HTML5 DOCTYPE, but there's a `<link>` tag before. Move this tag in the `<head>` section :

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    (...)
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.dharanandayoga.com/wp-content/themes/dharananda/admin.css" >
```

Comment: that link is not in the header.php, I can´t find where it is, but do you think is the problem why IE doesn´t center the wrapper? I mean, it points to an admin.css not the style.css

Comment: Even if this css isn't used, IE won't be able to find the Doctype (which **MUST** be on the very very first line), and load Quirks Mode. You can note it switching to "IE 8 compatibility / IE 8 standards". You must find where this link is added and remove it (or move it).

Comment: well, I couldn´t find where it´s calling that, thank you anyway

Comment: hey I found it and it fixes it!! thank you very much, now i´m organizing the code.